# Send some data to server and Fetch it

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, winforms, connection

A specific client (The Teacher) is supposed to send some data to the server and others clients (Students) should be able to get those data messages. um... Maybe think of it as a Text Messenger.

[image]

The data is just some simple text, no big stuff going on.

I want to know what's the best approach to do this ? I looked into WCF and it seems complicated. Tried some demo files and couldn't manage to get it work.

I also know PHP/Mysql. Does it make sense to insert those data into a mysql table ? I don't think it would be a good idea. It won't be any close to real-time speed.

**EDIT : The Application is in windows forms (C# lang) and Server application/service can by anything.**

I am not sure about the server side. So i can be a linux webserver (php&mysql) or a windows based application as well.

**EDIT 2** : I have no experience with ASP.NET and I don't know to code or make ASP applications.

Comment: How linux is involved here and what's the role of a server? Also what kind of application? Windows forms? Web forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [ASP.NET SignalR](http://signalr.net/). Either that or use Sockets/WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you say it should be some kind of Text Messenger paradigm I'm still not sure what's the role of server? Logging? Auth?

Anyway [this article](http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/) would be a good start I guess. Pay attention to pros and cons.

Comment: Yes. The role of the server is for Auth and Logging those text messages. and I am going to check out the link. Thanks!